# kotlin - Is there a way to merge two lists?

Tags: list, kotlin, merge

```
val current = listOf(
    Item(0, "url_0", "content_0"),
    Item(1, "url_1", "content_1"),
    Item(2, "url_2", "content_2"),
    Item(3, "url_3", "content_3"),
    Item(4, "url_4", "content_4"),
    Item(5, "url_5", "content_5")
)

val contentModify = listOf(
    Item(0, "url_0", "content_0"),
    Item(1, "url_1", "content_1"),
    Item(2, "url_2", "content_20"), // modify
    Item(3, "url_3", "content_30"), // modify
    Item(4, "url_4", "content_40"), // modify
    Item(5, "url_5", "content_5")
)

val urlModify = listOf(
    Item(0, "url_0", "content_0"),
    Item(1, "url_1", "content_1"),
    Item(2, "url_2", "content_2"),
    Item(3, "url_3", "content_3"),
    Item(4, "url_40", "content_4"), // modify
    Item(5, "url_50", "content_5") // modify
)

val content = current.filterNot(contentModify::contains)
val url = current.filterNot(urlModify::contains)
```

I made [content], [url] to find the changed points by comparing [contentModify] and [urlModify] modified in different places with [current] .
I want to combine the two results to make one edit list, but I am wondering if there is a way to merge them if the Id values ​​are the same.
Is there a way to combine these two results in kotlin??

Comment: A friend of mine has a blog on Kotlin aimed at beginners. Check out https://www.typealias.com He covers stuff like this

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what elements the final list should contain...

If you want a list of all items that are changed (but with the old values) the simple way is to use a set: `(url + content).toSet()`
This instruction produces a set that contains the following items:

- Item(2, "url_2", "content_2")
- Item(3, "url_3", "content_3")
- Item(4, "url_4", "content_4")
- Item(5, "url_5", "content_5")

but this list doesn't contain the updated data, so I suppose that you want the following list:

- Item(2, "url_2", "content_20")
- Item(3, "url_3", "content_30")
- Item(4, "url_40", "content_40")
- Item(5, "url_50", "content_5")

For this there isn't any built-in function so you should implement something like:

```
// your version of content and url are sublists of current but 
// you need the updated items (from contentModify and urlModify)
val content = contentModify.filterNot(current::contains)
val url = urlModify.filterNot(current::contains)

val mergedList = (content + url)
        .groupBy{it.id}
        .values
        .flatMap{ items -> 
            sequenceOf(if(items.size == 2){Item(items[0].id, items[0].content, items[1].url)} else {items.first()})
        }
```